# Redirect based on log-in status per JavaScript

Tags: users, javascript, redirect, login

I want to check if a user is logged in. If he is, I want to redirect him to page A, and if he isn’t to page B.

The redirect should happen per JavaScript after a button has been clicked – so I need the status or the URL to be available in JavaScript. How can I get these data from WordPress into JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if a user is logged in use `is_user_logged_in()`.

To redirect a visitor use `wp_redirect($location, $status = 302)`.

You can combine both:

```
<?php

$location = 'http://localhost';

if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    $location = admin_url( '/' );

wp_redirect( $location );
```

In JavaScript (sort of):

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpse_73701_button' );

function wpse_73701_button()
{
    $location = is_user_logged_in() ? admin_url( '/' ) : 'http://localhost';

    print "<button onclick='window.location.href=\"$location\"'>Click!</button>";
}
```

You could also just create JavaScript variables and use them in your scripts:

```
<script>
var isLoggedIn = <?php print is_user_logged_in() ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;
var redirectTo = '<?php print is_user_logged_in() ? admin_url( '/' ) : 'http://localhost'; ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: You pass the new $location value to JavaScript. I made an update to my answer with an oversimplified example for that.

Comment: Thanks for Reply.i am new to wordpress.i have Html button<input type="button" value="Check Login"> how can i check on this button or can i write your function in function.php.pls suggest me steps to do this.

Comment: I made another update, showing ho to populate JavaScript variables with the information. The question how these variables could be **used** in JavaScript is a separate one and on topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Make that a separate question please. Questions hidden in comments are not very useful, because the search engine will never find them.

Comment: Thanks your answer helpful to me.but can you explain just want to learn how can i call your suggested "function wpse_73701_button()" function on button click.

Comment: @toscho, Is it the right way to parse php code inside javascript?

Comment: @say You could also use `wp_localize_script()`. That depends on the context. If you have further questions, ask a new question please.